# Scrolable Tabs or Navigation Drawer for navigation in Android app?

Tags: mobile, navigation, android, mobile-application

I am making Zodiac app, and I there are these categories of zodiac in my app:

- daily horoscope,
- weekly horoscope,
- monthly horoscope,
- daily love horoscope

I am not sure what type of navigation I should use, Navigation Drawer or Scrollabe Tabs:

**Scrolabe Tabs pros:**

- visibility
- easier to access all types of zodiac

**Scrolabe Tabs cons:**

- slower loading of zodiac
- you don't want to read every day weekly or monthly horoscope, just daily and love daily.

Navigation Drawer pros:

- focus on daily horoscope
- faster loading of app

**Navigation Drawer cons:**

- poor visibility of weekly, monthly and love daily horoscope.

[image]

This is how app currently looks without Scrolable Tabs.

Comment: Beautiful visual design, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a lot of discussion lately about [killing the hamburger menu](http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/24/before-the-hamburger-button-kills-you/), but before you start diving into what types of design elements you want, you should look at the information architecture (granted, pretty simple in this case) and probably do a bit of research:

1. How long do you expect users to engage with your app on a daily/weekly/monthly basis?
2. Do people *really* care about horoscopes other than their own? If so, how much? If they care about their own, and hardly ever engage with any others, they should be allowed to set their own as default (leading to nav drawer making sense to access settings).
3. How do people prefer to view horoscopes? Would they prefer to see a list of zodiac signs, then choose duration? Or duration first?

Here are 2 options.
On the left, we assume duration is more important than sign.
When you click an individual sign, you get the detail view for that sign and duration simultaneously.

On the right, we assume sign is more important than duration.
When you click an individual sign, you get the horoscope for that sign at a predetermined duration (I assumed day here, but that may not be what users want most). I'm willing to bet that this is going to better serve users.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxbQxr.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I also think that second solution is whay better. Detail view + tabs with horoscope duration. What about navigation drawer? Should I use it for accessing settings, about app, rate app and other stuff like that?

Comment: That makes sense. You should probably read up on the Android design guidelines for the action bar: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Comment: This is an old question, but if you're still looking for an ideal solution, Google's Material Design guidelines for layout are here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html